# Difference between if(file) and if(file.good())?

Tags: c++, filestream

So I looked here on info on how to check for whether a file exists or not:

[The best way to check if a file exists using standard C/C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-using-standard-c-cplusplus)

They say `if(ifile)` before checking and then adding an `else` statement. I usually put `if(myfile.good())` to check for the same thing.

Is there a difference in how it operates?

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good. Especially look at the state chart provided on them. There is 1 subtle difference between `good()` and the `bool` operator. `good()` returns true only if *none* of the stream's flags are set. The `bool` operator returns true if `good()` is true, OR if only the `eofbit` flag is set.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So is it good practice to check both bool and good?

Comment: Might be. But for my purposes (I only actually cared if the file existed, not whether the bits matched perfectly), one or the other was fine.

Anyway, mark this as answered?

Comment: @Nina it really depends on context

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of checking if a file stream is opened successfully, both [`good()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) and the [`bool` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) are identical.

There is only 1 subtle difference between `good()` and the `bool` operator, and that is `good()` returns true only if *none* of the stream's state flags are set, whereas the `bool` operator returns true if either `good()` is true or if only the `eofbit` flag is set. So this difference doesn't come into play until you start reading data from the stream.

Note that the stream also has an [`is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open) method, as well.

That being said - that article's code only checks if a file can be *opened*, not if the file *exists*. A file can exist but you might not have rights to open it. A better way to check for *existence* is to use [`std::filesystem::exists()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists), which that article predates. Just note that checking for a file's existence prior to opening/creating the file will introduce a race condition. Another process could create/delete the file after you check its existence and before you open/create the file yourself.